# Querying Salesforce Activity History using Power Query raises DataSource.Error

Tags: salesforce, powerbi, powerquery, m

I think what I am doing is quite simple but hitting an unexpected error.

When I navigate the Salesforce.com Object Database using Power Query, and attempt to access the `Activity History` table I receive the following error.

```
DataSource.Error: entity type OpenActivity does not support query
Details:
    List
```

Is there such thing as unqueryable tables from Salesforce Object Library or can I access the table using a different method in PowerQuery? List doesn't seem to work...

```
let
    Source = Salesforce.Data("https://login.salesforce.com/", [CreateNavigationProperties = true]),
    SFDC_ActivityHistory = SFDC{[Name="ActivityHistory"]}[Data]
in
    SFDC_ActivityHistory
```

I do my usual login and then provide organization wide security credentials. Other tables work fine like accounts and opportunities.

Comment: hmm I see there is a column `hidden` which is set to `true`.

Comment: also looks like it might be better to come in through the `task` and `event` objects.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityHistory Table cannot be accessed directly, but you could get query access to it as the child relationship of a primary object. For instance:

```
Select Name, (Select Subject, ActivityType from ActivityHistories) from Account
```

Please refer to the last section, "Usage", of the document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm